# Add realtime database with android studio firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android 
{

    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.asus.salestrackingsystem"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

but still cant success to add realtime database , firebase assistant keep asking to add the realtime database to your app . anyone can help me?

Comment: I suggest not using the Firebase assistant at all and just using the steps in the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start

Comment: im already try to not using firebase assistant and follow step by step but still my data cant be add in database still null

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below links.

https://blog.mindorks.com/firebase-realtime-database-android-tutorial

https://github.com/MChehab94/Firebase-Realtime-Database-Demo

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-realtime-database-crud/

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Firebase/article.html

https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/firebase/firebase-database-tutorial/

https://proandroiddev.com/firebase-android-playground-realtime-database-560d4e18404a

Answer (score 0):

add these dependencies to integrate firebase realtime database:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0' // this is for user registration
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5' // this for database 
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5' // this is for core functionality 
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4' // this is for notifications
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5' // this is for storage 
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1' // this is for user authentication


classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // this will be added in project level gradle file
```

Comment: im already add it but still cant connected between database with app

Comment: no, you did not add these all dependencies. according to your question

Comment: after i reading your comment , i add all that dependencies in my project but still not work it all